# Удаление пробелов из строки с помощью filter

Tags: функции, haskell, функциональное-программирование

Есть строка вида:
`"Remove blanks from a string"`

Необходимо получить строку вида: `"Removeblanksfromastring"`

Вопрос: Как можно удалить пробелы из строки используя функцию filter?

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
filter (/=' ') "Remove blanks from a string"
```